# sscanf parsing issue with numeric input - returning unexpected results

Tags: c

I'm trying to parse a string to number using `sscanf` but it does not parse correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_LINES_BUFFER sizeof(int)

int main()
{
  ...
  ...
  // get number of lines
  char number[NUMBER_OF_LINES_BUFFER];
  int number_of_lines = 0;
  while (number_of_lines < 1)
  {
    print_message("Enter number of lines. Then enter\n");
    fgets(number, NUMBER_OF_LINES_BUFFER, stdin);

    if (sscanf(number, "%d", &number_of_lines) == true)
    {
      printf("number_of_lines: %d\n", number_of_lines);
      if (number_of_lines < 1)
      {
        print_message("ERROR: should be a positive integer.\n");
      }
    }
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

It should parse `"0012\n"` to `12`. But instead parses it to `1`.

Comment: your buffer just has 4 elements/chars. from `man fgets`: fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream

Comment: `sscanf` returns an `int`.  Comparing it to `true` is not good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform. So you're declaring `char number[4];`. This has room for 3 characters and the null terminator. When you enter `0012`, it's only reading `001`.

Make it bigger.

```
#define NUMBER_OF_LINES_BUFFER 10
```

Comment: Did you try printing `number`? Then you would have seen that it didn't contain `0012\n`.